# How to create a window in secondary monitor in win10 app

Tags: winapi

I am very new to the win10 dev, and I am trying to create a win10 app which will create a floating window in all the monitors the system is connected to. So far I am successful in using GDI API to create window in my primary monitor, but it is not working on my secondary monitor, I cannot get why it is not working even when I am using the API as mentioned in the microsoft page.

Below is my code

```
// Register the window class.
WNDCLASSEX wcex = { sizeof(WNDCLASSEX) };
wcex.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
wcex.lpfnWndProc = DXGIDraw::WndProc;
wcex.cbClsExtra = 0;
wcex.cbWndExtra = sizeof(LONG_PTR);
wcex.hInstance = HINST_THISCOMPONENT;
wcex.hbrBackground = NULL;
wcex.lpszMenuName = NULL;
wcex.hCursor = LoadCursor(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wcex.lpszClassName = L"DemoApp";

RegisterClassEx(&wcex);

m_hwnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_LAYERED,
    L"DemoApp",
    L"Demo App",
    0,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    CW_USEDEFAULT,
    HWND_DESKTOP,
    NULL,
    HINST_THISCOMPONENT,
    NULL
);

const int nWidth = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN);
const int nHeight = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN);

CImage img;

DISPLAY_DEVICE ddd;
ZeroMemory(&ddd, sizeof(ddd));
ddd.cb = sizeof(ddd);
for (int i = 0; EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, i, &ddd, 0); i++)
{
    if (ddd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_ACTIVE) {
        //Active monitor
    }
    if (ddd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_PRIMARY_DEVICE) {
        //Primary monitor
    }
    else {
        //other types
    }
}

//The following API supposed to work for all the monitors, but this API is not working. This is where I need attention.
HDC hdcScreen = CreateDC(ddd.DeviceName, NULL, NULL, NULL);
//But if I use below API I can get it working for the primary monitor only, still trying to understand why
//HDC hdcScreen = CreateDC(L"DISPLAY", NULL, NULL, NULL);
HDC hDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hdcScreen);
HBITMAP hBmp = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdcScreen, nWidth, nHeight);
HBITMAP hBmpOld = (HBITMAP)SelectObject(hDC, hBmp);
img.Draw(hDC, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight, 0, 0, nWidth, nHeight);

//Add layered window
BLENDFUNCTION blend = { 0 };
blend.BlendOp = AC_SRC_OVER;
blend.SourceConstantAlpha = 255;
blend.AlphaFormat = AC_SRC_ALPHA;
POINT ptLocation = { 0, 0 };
SIZE szWnd = { nWidth, nHeight };
POINT ptSrc = { 0, 0 };
BOOL status1 = UpdateLayeredWindow(m_hwnd, hdcScreen, &ptLocation, &szWnd, hDC, &ptSrc, 0, &blend, ULW_ALPHA);

//Set window's position
BOOL status = SetWindowPos(m_hwnd, HWND_TOPMOST, 0, 0, 0, 0, SWP_NOMOVE | SWP_NOSIZE);

hr = m_hwnd ? S_OK : E_FAIL;
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    BOOL status;
    status = ShowWindow(m_hwnd, SW_MAXIMIZE);
    status = UpdateWindow(m_hwnd);
}

SelectObject(hDC, hBmpOld);
DeleteObject(hBmp);
DeleteDC(hDC);
ReleaseDC(NULL, hdcScreen);
}
```

Comment: How is this C#?

Comment: the question I asked can be answered by c# developer also, I am not looking for the code here, I just need an idea on how to proceed, I am even okay if somebody provides a c# code.

Comment: @User13579 To be fair a C# programmer does not necessarily understand C++ code. Because providing code is pretty much a must on SO when asking a question and you provided your example code in C++ in my opinion it shouldn't have been tagged with C#. Because asking for "How is this done in language X" is not a SO question.

Comment: This isn't really a language question at all. It's a question about winapi.

Comment: SetWindowPos parameters are wrong

Comment: @Anders what should i change the parameters to?

Comment: I dont understand why people are demoting my question. the c# tag has been removed already, what else is wrong with this?

Comment: The placement of a windows is by using X,Y in `SetWindowPos` (or at the `CreateWindow` call). You understand that you will have to create several Windows, on for each monitor, right?

Answer (score 1):

`EnumDisplayDevices` is the wrong API for this job. You need to use [`EnumDisplayMonitors`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaymonitors) which gives you the monitor coordinates directly.

Comment: I have updated the code with `EnumDisplayMonitors`, I also tried that, but it did not work, I have updated the code, please check it

Comment: Sorry, but `EnumDisplayMonitors` works fine. You can't modify the question to ask a different question. I reverted your edit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to retreive the bounding rectangle for the desired monitor within the [virtual screen](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/gdi/the-virtual-screen), and then you can position a window within that rectangle as desired.  Use [`EnumDisplayMonitors()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaymonitors) to get the rectangle of each moinitor.  Or, if you have an `HMONITOR` handle to a specific monitor, you can use [`GetMonitorInfo()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmonitorinfow).